# Debug Jenkins Slave Setup?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I've got some desktops running Windows 7 that I'm trying to setup as Jenkins slaves.  The slaves work if I connect using the command line provided on the slave status page, such as `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkins-master.mycompany.com:8080/computer/slave1/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 42abcdef123456abef222ccc11`.  But if I connect using the java web start button on the status page it fails with an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I get the same error on 3 different slave machines.  In all three cases I'm launching from a browser running on the slave machine.

I'd like to have the slaves running as a Windows service.  I could set it up so the service issues the java command line that does work, but I'd prefer to use the service facilities provided by jenkins itself.  Plus I'd simply like to understand why the web start method isn't working.  How do I go about debugging this?